# Processing - Accessing classes in subdirectory

Tags: processing

I'm hitting this issue in this latest project where I'm looking to organise my code into subdirectories. However by doing so, the main application .pde file can't "see" the classes in the subdirectory.

Example - Say my folder structure is:

```
PFoo /
  - PFoo.pde
    PSystem /
      - PSystem.pde
      - Particle.pde
```

With PFoo.pde as my main application file, I can't seem to access the PSystem class or Particle class. Now, I guess the general consensus would be to develop a library to import or just deal with all the .pde files being in the same directory, however I'm wondering if there is something simple that I'm missing here that will enable me to quickly sort out the numerous class files that will be created. Something like a `include "PSystem/PSystem.pde"` or....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a tree structure in the Processing IDE unfortunately.
All your tabs from Processing end up being nested and compiled into a single Java class when you press Run.

I recommend using [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr2) and you can easily nest your classes into java packages.
Additionally you can use the [Proclipsing](http://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/) plugin which integrates nicely and makes it easier to manage libraries/export sketches/etc.

Comment: ahh I see, well it's no biggy I guess, just means collaborators will have to deal with working out of the same directory. I've tried to steer away from eclipse as I like to have a lightweight dev environment but I might have to reconsider staying away from bloaty IDE's; that plugin however does look interesting. Cheers

Comment: Eclipse is a lot nicer compared to the processing IDE if you are collaborating with others or work on projects larger than a simple sketch.. sure its bulky but you get intellisense, javadoc and version control.